# Curious about where my controllers are when webapi is published

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

Not so much a direct programming query - more just for info/knowledge...

When I click on Publish (VS2012 RC), and I look in the release folder, I can only see folders for bin, content, images, scripts and views.

There is no controllers folder.

Is this because VS packages up everything into the DLLs within the BIN folder?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Yes, it packs your controller classes in DLLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DLLs` inside your `bin` folder has the code for the controllers and other class files(Ex : Your Model classes).  If you use any decompiling tool, you can see that.

[image]

DLL (dynamic-link library) files contain the executable code for the Web site, such as the class file that you created. Your application will works fine with those DLLs because all your code(your methods/ properties etc..) is available in that.

Answer (score 1):

Your controllers (and any other `.cs` files) are compiled into a dll in the `bin` folder.